# Magento2: How to fix add to cart not showing in product details page

Tags: magento2, addtocart, recaptcha, product-detail-page

When I click on product details page not showing  **add to cart**
But when I search in inspector  it's there but not showing on site 

**console error:**

> Error: Missing required parameters: site key

How can i resolve ?

Comment: can you show your captcha code?

Comment: Do you mean Add to Cart button not visible on product detail page?

Comment: which captcha code

Comment: @RaviSoni ss ...

Comment: I suggest, to check with M2 default theme. If its showing than check with your theme addtocart.phtml file.

Comment: ho ok will check...

Comment: Are you using the default Magento theme? Or  Any extension used for price or add to cart functionality.

Comment: it's caused by extension in my site